# Conflictos al hacer npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, paquetes-npm

Estoy teniendo un conflicto pesado a la hora de hacer `npm i` en mi proyecto de `React`.

Éste proyecto no lo empecé yo, sino que la empezó una empresa externa, y ahora me toca a mi ir modificando el código con las tareas que me asignen.

El problema está en que para actualizar o instalar un paquete, me saltan varios errores, obligandome a utilizar `npm i --force`

Sinceramente nunca me pasó, busqué en varios lados y hasta en ChatGPT pero no encuentro una respuesta...

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR! @emotion/react@"^11.8.1" from react-select@5.7.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-select
npm ERR! react-select@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 29 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/amchart4-react
npm ERR!  amchart4-react@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from amchart4-react@1.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/amchart4-react
npm ERR! amchart4-react@"^1.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Si es necesario, paso lo que me muestra el `log`, el cual es más extenso.

Cualquier consulta o ayuda es bienvenida.